# How to add context menu for a Nat Table?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, nattable, nebula

I want to add a context menu for a NatTable. 
I have a view where other controls are also present. Context menu should only pop-up when I right click anywhere on the NatTable. How can I achieve this? 
Also I wanted to know, how to add context menu through commands and handlers for NatTable. Is there a special way to do this for NatTable?
Please let me know how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the blog post I have published a while ago:

http://blog.vogella.com/2015/02/03/nattable-context-menus-with-eclipse-menus/

Comment: Hi @Dirk Fauth, sorry for question, I am new to Java. I would like to implement context menu for nattable and insert `copy` command. I have got file NatTableFactory.java, where I do create `column header layer` and so on. When I insert there `BodyMenuConfiguration` class and other stuff from your example, it does not work. In Eclipse I can see _"The type NatTableFactory.BodyMenuConfiguration is never used locally"_. What do I miss?

Comment: Probably you are not creating an instance of that class and registering that instance with the NatTable instance.